# Tabular items are not aligned correctly

Tags: vertical-alignment, tabularx

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}


 \vspace{-3pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textbf{
        London School of Economics and Political Science (LSE)
      } & 
         London, United Kingdom \\
      \textit{\small 
        Data Science and Big Data Analytics (Summer School); Grade: A
      } & \textit{\small 
        July 2018 -- August 2018} \\     
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-5pt}


 \end{document}
```

How it looks like (see the left misalignment of the two rows)
[image]

Comment: Add a `%` after `\textbf{`, otherwise a space will be inserted there. It should be `\textbf{%`. Or, since a table cell limits the font change to the current cell, you can simply replace `\textbf{text}` by `\bfseries text`.

Comment: The same issue is not present in the `\textit{\small` lines because the `\small` absorbs the line end/space that follows it.